# CentOS 7 AMPPS Launch Issue

Tags: centos, centos7, lamp, lib, ampps

I am in the process of setting up a Linux Based AMPPS LAMP box for local web development needs before the projects go live. I have been following this installation guide for AMPPS website, on a  fresh install of CentOS: https://www.ampps.com/wiki/Installing_AMPPS_on_Linux#Important_Locations

The following is stated in the instructions:

> First Run of AMPPS When you run AMPPS for the first time make sure your Internet connection is active. Note: AMPPS doesn't support proxy
>   yet. So you must have a Direct Internet Connection.
>
> Now open /usr/local/ampps/Ampps from Explorer, this will take some
>   time as it is setting up AMPPS for your Linux. If you are using Ubuntu
>   OS then you have to start Ampps from terminal with sudo privilege.
>
> `cd /usr/local/ampps`
>
> `sudo ./Ampps`

Upon entering ./Ampps in as root, the terminal returns the following:

```
./Ampps: error while loading shared libraries: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory
```

I have done a little of a search and turned up basic fixes, such as:

```
yum install libXrender.so.1
```

Even with the libraries installed it throwing the same error.

Any help would be great,
Sorry if my post lacks anything its my first :)

Thanks in advance,
Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to do the trick guys, Thanks anyways :D

```
$ yum groupinstall "X Window System" "Desktop" "Desktop Platform" "Fonts"
```